# How can i add new environment in API wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

How can I add new environment in API Management WSO2 in current there are two environments by default

Comment: What do you mean by environment? Production and SandBox aren't environments, they are endpoint types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are referring different gateway environments. If so please go through the [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Maintaining+Separate+Production+and+Sandbox+Gateways) which explains how you can add gateway environments.